# Changing the Audio Source of a Player in a NextJS App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-audio

I have two functional components written in a NextJS (React) app. One of the components provides a '*select track from a tracklist*' `fn` and the other component - the `player` component - has a custom HTML5 `audio` element where the source, `src`, is updated by the track selected on the `tracklist` component, via a Context hook.

The problem is that although (I think) the `src` is updated 'onClicking' a `track` from the `tracklist`, there is no call to the `.load()` method after a new `track` is selected, which is probably why the `src` doesn't actually change - if you press play the same initialised track will continue to play:

- On page load, the **initialised track** will play (when I click `play`). If I select a *new* track, the **same initialised track** will continue playing if I press play (even though I selected a new `track`) - clearly, the `src` for the `audio` element has not actually updated.

Here is the interpolated string which 'should' update the value of `src`:

`/[..]/[..]/${track}.mp3`

I 'think' that the path is right because I can `console.log` `track` and it is does correctly update `onClick`. But it seems that the player is not actually updating its source `src` when the user selected a new one.

**How can the source be updated?**

As an aside: the player has a `play` button and a `pause` button. Clicking either triggers a separate function. Is there a way to create hooks for `play` and `pause`? e.g. via `useState` or `useEffect`?

---

#### Code:

```
// the component will receive the user-selected {track} onClick
export default function MusicPlayer() {

  const { track } = useContext(AudioContext);

  function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("a1");
    audio.play();
  }

  function pause() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("a1");
    audio.pause();
  }

// ... /
  return (
    <audio id="a1">
          <source
            src={track}
            type="audio/mpeg"
          />
    </audio>
```

The following code will create an Audio element on a NextJS app:

```
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setAudio(new Audio(URL));
  }, []);
```

**The challenge I see it is to set the `src` (i.e. the `URL` parameter) via the Context hook, but I'm not entirely sure how!**

The context is essentially this:

```
const [trackToPlay, setTrackToPlay] = useState("Track-1");
const changeTrack = (chapter) => setTrackToPlay(chapter);
```

The below code shows how track can be selected from a list of tracks.

```
{[
    { chapter: "1" },
    { chapter: "2" },
              ].map((d) => (
                <div>
                  <div onClick={() => changeTrack(d.chapter)}>
                    <span className={styles.trackChapter}>{d.chapter}</span>{" "}
                  </div>
                </div>
))}
```

Comment: Where are you handling the click events to select a new track? Also, can you share the `AudioContext` code?

Comment: The `trackNames` are all buttons that set the state via a context hook to play the clicked on track. Currently the `play` button fires `onLoad()`, but it means that every time you click `play` (for instance after `pause`) the `track` will start from the beginning again.

Comment: "One of the components provides a 'select track from a tracklist' fn" - we'll need to also see the code for that component.

Comment: I updated the code section in the question.